# Get more data from a relationship table using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm building a web application using Yii framework, and i'm quite new to it. 
I have 3 db tables. One stores users, the second products, and the third is a relationship table that stores user_id, product_id and more info like the time the product was bought.

I configured a MANY_MANY relationship, and have no problem to get all the products the user has bought. However I can't figure out how can I get the extra info from the relationship table?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your association holds additional data, you can declare itself as a class `Purchase` and add these relationships:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'purchases' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Purchase', 'user_id'),
      // Products purchased by this user
      'products' => array(
        self::HAS_MANY, 'Product', 'product_id',
        'through' => 'purchases',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Purchase extends CActiveRecord
{
  // You need to add this, since every purchase is uniquely identified 
  // by user and product. Surrogate 'id' key is also fine
  public function primaryKey()
  {
    return array('user_id', 'product_id');
  }

  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
      'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
    );
  }
}
```

Remove remaining `MANY_MANY` relationships from `User` and `Product` models. Note the usage of [through](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through) relationship. Fetching data might look like this:

```
$users = User::model()->with('purchases.product')->findAll();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  echo $user->username . "<br>";
  echo 'Purchases<br>';
  foreach ($user->purchases as $purchase) {
    echo "Date: {$purchase->purchased_at}<br>";
    echo "Product: {$purchase->product->name} <br>";
  }
  echo '<hr>';
}
```

This will perform only one query from `User` table joining on another two tables. Also `User::model()->with('products')` will efficiently find user(s) with products they bought. Your DB scheme can remain the same, except you'll need to add composite primary key in the association table.

See [this article in the Yii wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/) for a detailed explanation.